# partial differentiation of a variable w.r.t. its time derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

What will be the partial derivative :

$$\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial\dot\theta}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial\dot\theta}{\partial\theta}$$

where, $\theta = \theta(t)$ and $\dot\theta = \frac{d\theta}{dt}$

would these be zero or something else??

Answer (score 2):

The expressions you wrote are meaningless, at least without context.

If I have a function $f(x,y,z)$, I can only calculate the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, $y$ or $z$. Deriving always means with respect to one of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you interpret them as *functions*, as in mathematical analysis, what you wrote makes no sense (it's not even zero).

If they are *quantities* of some kind (e.g. coordinates), like in physics or other applications, then you can write different *functions*, but which represent the same *quantity*. Take locally the inverse $\theta\mapsto t(\theta)$, and using the Leibniz notation:
$$
\frac{dt}{d\theta} = \frac{1}{\dot\theta}.
$$

This is a function of $\theta$, let's call it $\theta\mapsto f(\theta)$, which as a *quantity* is equal to $1/\dot\theta$.

Now, as a *quantity*:
$$
\dot\theta(t)= \dot\theta(t(\theta)),
$$

and:
$$
\frac{d\dot\theta}{d\theta} = \frac{d\dot\theta}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\theta} = \ddot\theta\frac{1}{\dot\theta} = \frac{\ddot\theta}{\dot\theta}
$$

Viceversa, 
$$
\frac{d\theta}{d\dot\theta} = \frac{\dot\theta}{\ddot\theta}.
$$

Lastly, if the quantity $d\theta/d\dot\theta$ appears in calculation with Lagrangians, or in general functions or functionals in the form:
$$
L = L(\theta, \dot\theta, t,\dots),
$$

then $\theta$ and $\dot\theta$ are simply *different* variables, and:
$$
\frac{\partial\dot\theta}{\partial\theta} = \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial\dot\theta} = 0,
$$

just like, if $F(x,y)=x$, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$.

Comment: I am not talking senseless here. I faced this problem while solving the dynamics of a double pendulum. For dynamics, we calculate: $$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot q}$$ where, $$q = \left[\theta_1;\theta_2\right]$$. In this case I was getting a partial derivative $$\frac{\partial\cos\theta}{\partial\dot\theta}$$

Comment: Oh I see. In *that* case, you have a function $L(\theta, \dot\theta)$, and both $\theta$ and $\dot\theta$ appear as *different variables*. So, in your case, $\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial\dot\theta}$ and $\frac{\partial\dot\theta}{\partial\theta}$ are simply zero.

I'll write it in the answer.